# How to detect memory error when running a C program?

Tags: c, runtime-error

I known GCC is a compiler and it is not its job to detect runtime error, but is there any method to show runtime error such as memory error during runtime? As this will be really helpful for debugging.

I am trying to mimic a memory error in C. In the following code, I used an endless loop to print elements in an array, which I suppose should yield some kind of error. But the the program just stopped after printing some 0s and random numbers.

The codes are as follows.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf("%llu elements in arr\n", sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int));
    int ix = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("%d, ", arr[ix++]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the command lines I used.

```
gcc .\buggy.c -o buggy -Wall
.\buggy.exe
```

Here are the outputs.

```
5 elements in arr
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 8, 8, 946979856, 684, -308276498, 32759, 0, 0, -308252600, 32759, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -308276218, 32759, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1804065411, 32764, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1768117672, 32764, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1232, 1264, -1232, 1232, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Here is the information of the gcc(UCRT to be specific) I installed on my windows 11 using msys2.

```
gcc.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: If you go out of bounds you will have *undefined behavior*. It's your responsibility as the programmer to make sure that your code does not have undefined behavior.

Comment: I guess the answer will be "No, it just is Undefined Behaviour". But you might get better answers if you go into detail what you mean by "memory error". Memory failure on hardware level, like bit flips due to radiation? Also, maybe the question you would like answered is "Why does this endless loop stop at all?", the answer to that might help you dissect the problem you are really wondering about.

Comment: As for the program stopping, that *is* very likely the "memory error" you expected. When the program goes so far out of bounds that it comes to an address that doesn't belong to your program, then the OS will get a signal and terminate your program.

Comment: On a different note, the result of `sizeof` is a value of type `size_t`. The correct format specifier for `size_t` values is `%zu`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type also leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/

Comment: Supposedly gcc should insert "stack canaries" but that has never worked reliably unless you tweak it manually. You could try compiling with `-fstack-protector-strong`. And for debugging purposes, `-fsanitize=address`.

Comment: You should be able to run your program using [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org) (or some equivalent on platforms where it's not available).  That gives very informative diagnostics on common memory errors that `gcc -fanalyze` can't catch.

Comment: It looks like you could enable more warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.